# Springboot application cannot be started due to java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not contain null elements

Tags: spring-boot

I am getting the following startup error with my SpringBoot application

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
07:13:51.810 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sources must not contain null elements
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:186)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:139)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:75)
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigImportArray(ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.propertySourceWithConfigImport(ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:109)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:178)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.getConfigImports(ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.cloud.commons.ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataMissingEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.example.oauth2resttemplate.Application.main(Application.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I do have the Application.class into the run method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.oauth2resttemplate")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

This issue comes up if I added a API jar as a dependenecy from another project. I checked the jar and it seems to be normal. It just uses annotation in the classes
For example

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the API parent pom was bringing some other dependencies, for example oauth, that causes this issue. It is because current SpringBoot application did not have the corresponding properties configured. I have to move out the incorrect dependencies from parent pom